# Loop through all textbox and dropdown controls on a webform and disable them

Tags: c#, webforms

Having some trouble with this one.  I want to loop through every textbox and dropdown control on a webform and disable them under cerrtain conditions.  I'm finding a lot of sample code for winforms, but apparently in a webform you can't use Control.Enabled because it doesn't exist.  I've got this, which (again) doesn't work because I'm using a webform:

```
private void DisableControls(Control con) 
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls) 
    {
        DisableControls(c);
    }
    con.Enabled = false;
}

private void EnableControls(Control con)
{
    if (con != null)
    {
        con.Enabled = true;
        EnableControls(con.Parent);
    }
}
```

and I would call them in my Page_Load event like so:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // If certain conditions exist, then...
        DisableControls(this);
        EnableControls(Button1);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know whether is import to travel all controls manually. But I used <asp:Panel...> I put all my controls which I want to Enable/Disable conditionally. And in code-behind I just put Pane1.Enabled = false, or true and disables/enables all the controls in side the Panel in on go.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using recursion ? I don't understand that part.

You can make your method generic

```
private void DisableControls<T>(IEnumerable<T> controls) where T: Control
{
    foreach(var control in controls)
    {
        control.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
DisableControls(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>());
DisableControls(this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>());
```

Comment: Error 13 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled' and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: yeah I noticed add,We should add a constraint.I have updated my answer check it

Comment: i didnt down votee you but you should either change your answer to something that works or delete it. @Selman22

Comment: i did Control does not have Enabled, you even said you noticed it.

Comment: if you add where T : Control constraint it will have Enabled!

Comment: no it will not have it. doesnt even make sense?!!? see which control you are referencing maybe its not under Web namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a walker:

```
public void ApplyToAllControls(Control node, Action<Control> lambda)
{
   lambda(node);

   foreach(Control c in node.Controls)
   {
       ApplyToAllControls(c, lambda);
   }
}
```

And implement two lambdas like this:

```
private void ControlDisabler(Control c)
{
    if(c != Button1)
    {
        c.Enabled = false;
    }
}

private void ControlEnabler(Control c)
{
    if(c != Button1)
    {
        c.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

You then invoke them this way:

```
ApplyToAllControls(root, ControlDisabler);
ApplyToAllControls(root, ControlEnabler);
```

There are surely some rough edges you can smooth out but you should already get the basic idea.

With currying you can even parameterize the lambdas but that's a bit far to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void DisableControls() 
{
    var Controls = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
    foreach (Control c in Controls) 
    {
       ((TextBox)c).Enabled = false;
    }

}

private void EnableControls()
{
    var Controls = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
    foreach (Control c in Controls) 
    {
       ((TextBox)c).Enabled = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Error 13 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled' and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

fastest solution you can use is change the

```
private void DisableControls(Control con)
```

to:

```
private void DisableControls(WebControl con)
```

that should work,
of course do the same in the loop....

and now the explanations, the class Control doesn't have a definition for Enabled it is defined in an upper level base class ( WebControl ), so this is why you need to use it to gain access to enabled .

EDIT:

just checked the code and it fails on the literal control that is new line ( it inherits directly from control )

so the only other thing you need to add is something like this:

```
foreach (WebControl con in form1.Controls.OfType<WebControl>())
        {
            con.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Comment: @Johnny Bones you know its nice if you close question as answered you know people helped you can show appreciation.